# Remove root password of Debian 9.1 (Stretch) IoT image

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack

My Beaglebone black is running Debian 9.1 (Stretch) IoT image. I am able to access BBB from serial terminal But unable to ssh login using 'root' user.

I executed below commands from serial terminal to remove 'root' user password:

```sh
root_password=$(cat /etc/shadow | grep root | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
sed -i -e 's:'$root_password'::g' /etc/shadow

sed -i -e 's:PermitEmptyPasswords no:PermitEmptyPasswords yes:g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i -e 's:UsePAM yes:UsePAM no:g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i -e 's:PermitRootLogin without-password:PermitRootLogin yes:g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

echo "debian  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >>/etc/sudoers
```

Comment: What?  You look like you're trying to allow root to log into your box with an empty password, even via ssh.  Are you setting up a honeypot?  Root should either never log in (log in as a real user and use `sudo`) or else root should log in using SSH keys.  In those scenarios, the root password doesn't actually matter.  Disable it by setting its hash to `*` in /etc/shadow.

Comment: Log in as a real user and using sudo too requires root password.

Comment: Logging in as a real user and using sudo requires the user's password, though with a /etc/sudoers line like `%sudo  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` (as you've noted, though you need to install it with `visudo`), it doesn't even require the user's password.  If the user logs in with an SSH key, the user doesn't need to have a password either.

Comment: It worked by just changing 'PermitRootLogin' value to 'yes' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. But yes, I still need to provide password. And password is 'root'.